# How to use mpi on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, installation, mpi

I have been searching for a way to use mpi on my mac but everything is very advanced.

I have successfully installed open-mpi using

```
brew install open-mpi
```

I have .c files ready for compiling and running. When I type:

```
mpicc -o <file> <file.c>
```

followed by

```
mpirun <file>
```

I get

> [xxxxx-MacBook-Pro.local:13623] [[44919,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad
>   parameter in file orted/pmix/pmix_server.c at line 262
>   [xxxxx-MacBook-Pro.local:13623] [[44919,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad
>   parameter in file ess_hnp_module.c at line 666
>
> It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process
>   is likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process
>   can fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
>   environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
>   here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
>   Open MPI developer):
>
> pmix server init failed
>   --> Returned value Bad parameter (-5) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS

I also get the same message when I enter:

```
mpirun -np 2 <file>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you run this successfully? `mpirun -np 2 hostname`

Comment: you might need to `export TMPDIR=/tmp` in order to prevent some paths from being truncated

Answer (score 55):

If I were you, I'd do following:

Installation of Open MPI is fairly straightforward

https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v2.0/

```
> tar xf openmpi-2.0.2.tar
> cd openmpi-2.0.2/
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/local
> make all
> make install
> $HOME/opt/usr/local/bin/mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 2.0.2

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
```

You can use super simple hello world for testing purposes

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int rank;
    int world;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world);
    printf("Hello: rank %d, world: %d\n",rank, world);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

After everything is in place, simply compile and run the code

```
$HOME/opt/usr/local/bin/mpicc -o hello ./hello.c
$HOME/opt/usr/local/bin/mpirun -np 2 ./hello
Hello: rank 0, world: 2
Hello: rank 1, world: 2
```

Works perfectly fine on macOS

**Update**

In case you are looking for `MPI` related environment on macOS, I suggest checking out concept of `modules`.

- building MPICH/OpenMPI - https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/
- modules - https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/

**Update**

There is an updated version of mentioned blog entry:

- https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-13-2-0/

Comment: After `make install` it should be `$HOME/opt/usr/local/bin/mpirun --version` (missing `/opt`).

Comment: .oOo. Thanks for spotting it. .oOo.

Comment: You might be also interested in two different topics: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-8-3-0/ and https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/ :)

Comment: Many thanks! Confirmed working on Mac OS X Ventura 13.4. I have to use this method because I can't create update lock in `/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks`. Also, I failed to fix permission with `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/homebrew`.

Comment: @ChienNguyen - thanks for confirming it at `13.4`! :) Good to know it still works as expected.

Answer (score 26):

Building on the answer provided by @Oo.oO.
Install `OpenMPI`.
It can be installed using `brew`.

`brew install openmpi`

Comment: Worked without a problem. Homebrew 2.1.10 on Mac 10.14.4 - thanks for this.

Comment: FYI: This can take hours if `gcc` needs to be built

Answer (score 7):

On some versions of Mac OS X / MacOS Sierra, the default temporary directory location is sufficiently long that it is easy for an application to create file names for temporary files which exceed the maximum allowed file name length, Which can cause this error.
so you should set the temporary directory using `export TMPDIR=/tmp`

more details here https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=osx

Answer (score 6):

If you have anaconda installed, this is the fastest option for me:

```
conda install mpi4py openmpi
```

Comment: `mpi4py ` is not a channel. Just `conda install -c anaconda openmpi`

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that during execution pmix offers an unnecesary exception of the form:

```
    PMIX ERROR: ERROR in file gds_ds12_lock_pthread.c at line 206
```

To prevent this, before the execution of main file always type this on the terminal prompt :

```
    export PMIX_MCA_gds=hash
```

This helps subside the pmix noice and has to be repeated every session.

Note:
The maximum number of slots that pmi allows is by default 2 in macs. A "slot" is the Open MPI term for an allocatable unit where we can
launch a process. This determines how many time we can run an instruction in a code.
To extend the number of slots carry out the following steps:

1.Create a hostfile with anyname

2.within the write:

```
      localhost slots = <#>
```

where #=no. of slots needed.

3. while compiling write the  following on the terminal prompt:

   ```
   mpicc  -hostfile -<filename>
   ```

   4. While running wite the following on the terminal prompt:

      mpirun -hostfile  -np <#>

   Although be weary of the last note,it isnt often needed and the file extention of the hostfile may become a problem with certain architectures , such as my own x86.